# How to create an Android project in Android Studio 3.0 beta 5?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

The beta 5 is released. I'm trying to create an Android project just like I used to, but it shows an IDEA-like window where I should choose what type of project I want to create with those options like "Java", "Groovy", "Gradle", "Kotlin"... Where're good ol' "activity"-templates?

**UPD**

I installed the Beta 5 on a virtual machine working on the same Xubuntu version that my real machine does. Everything works well. Perhaps the issue is somehow related to the fact that I previously installed the Rider IDE by JetBrains. But still, Rider has been installed for a while, and it did not affect the installation of the previous beta versions of the Studio

Comment: You need to pick a language before you create Activities...

Comment: @cricket_007 Okay, I click "File->New->Project". I see the lang options. I select Java and see "1.8" in the SDK field. I click "next" and see "create project from template" where we have just "console app". "Next": Project name. "Finish". And I Have now some Java project. Not Android. Similar things happen when I choose other lang options.

Comment: sounds like the what happens when you use base intellij idea without the android plugin

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, that's exactly what I'm talking about. First time I got the issue just after updating my Beta 4 to the 5. Now I downloaded Beta 5 to a separate directory and the issue is still here.

Comment: Feel free to create a ticket on Android Studio bug tracker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I detected that Android plugins were not found & not connected to the studio. That was weird. I clicked "Download & Enable" and after several downloading and update processes the studio began working as it used to.